# Normalization of a 3D matrix in python (LSTM/Keras input)

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, lstm, normalization

LSTM input matrix has a shape like this in Keras:

```
(sample size, number of time steps, number of features)
```

How can I normalize this input using `MinMaxScaler` function in python? Suppose that we have an input matrix with this shape: `(10,3,2)`.

Answer (score -1):

`MinMaxScaler` is designed to work with tabular data of only two dimensions, so I suspect what you want to do is something like:

```
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    X[:, i, :] = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X[:, i, :])
```